# PHP mail function not sending email to Gmail account?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, plugins

I am working on a WordPress plugin in which I send email using the PHP mail function, but there is a problem with the mail function. It sends emails to my non-Gmail account, but it's doesn't send emails to my Gmail account. I am using following code:

```
function send_mail()
        {
            global $wpdb;
            $to = 'mymail@gmail.com';
            $subject = 'Hello';
            $name='my name';
            $from="name@mydomain.com";

            $message = "
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>my title</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div>
                <tt> ".Hii How Are you."</tt>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>";

            $header  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $header .= "From: ".$name."<".$from.">\r\n";

            mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code, or is there some issue with the mail function? If any alternate method is available to send email, please give me the link.

Comment: check `error_log` why the email is not been sent. there something to do with your server may be smtp is not configured..

Comment: you better use `phpmailer` https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/ for php.

Comment: It may be becouse gmail does not accept email from non verified domain.

Comment: Your message's subject and body very likely triggered the SPAM filter, you miss "Check this out [random link here]" and you've made _en plein_ .Try sending a more structured message and see if the problem is still there

Comment: @zzlalani: is phpmailer works on IIS server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17066482/setting-up-phpmailer-on-iis7

Answer (score 3):

Check if adding fifth variable works for you... here is my code for sending emails.

```
    if( mail( $recipient, $subject, $message, $headers, "-f noreply@mydomain.com"))
        return "success";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the spam folder, It might be there. Its a server issue, it hapened to me also many times. Gmail blocks mails or sends to spam from some servers due to some reasons. Ask your server provider to check why mails are not going to gmail inbox.

Answer (score 0):

use the code sample as below, email address in <> and that last paramter worked for me.

```
$headers = 'From: <test@test.com>' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: <test@test.com>';

mail('<myEmail@gmail.com>', 'the subject', 'the message', $headers,
  '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

It is the answer provided in [PHP mail() function will not send to gmail but will send to my non-gmail account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021655/php-mail-function-will-not-send-to-gmail-but-will-send-to-my-non-gmail-account) by ARH3, which i have tried and tested